# Problemas al hacer deploy en Render

Tags: java, mysql, docker

estoy intenando hacer un deploy en render con Dockerfile en un proyecto de springboot conectado a una base de datos de Clever Cloud.

Cuando hago el deploy me tira estos errores:

> ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool
> : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications
> link failure
>
> WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator
> : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

> WARN 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation
> : HHH90000025: MySQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly
> using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be
> selected by default)

**Mi application properties:**

```
#Prueba
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clinica_odontologica
#spring.datasource.username=root
#spring.datasource.password=admin
#Produccion
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://uwu6bdixfpkyhosy:m6OqIfZoN7F6I5MhISCL@bot3j86rojla3ekare91-mysql.services.clever-cloud.com:3306/bot3j86rojla3ekare91
spring.datasource.username=uwu6bdixfpkyhosy
spring.datasource.password=m6OqIfZoN7F6I5MhISCL
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=30000
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
server.port=8080
application.security.jwt.secret-key=404E635266556A586E3272357538782F413F4428472B4B6250645367566B5970
application.security.jwt.expiration=86400000
application.security.jwt.refresh-token.expiration=604800000
file.upload-dir=C:/Users/Lautaro/Desktop/Desarrollo-web/Proyectos/proyecto-clinica-odontologica/imagenes
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=5MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=5MB
```

**Mi Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk

MAINTAINER lautaroCenizo

# Copia el archivo JAR construido en la fase de construcción
COPY target/Clinica-Odontologica-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar clinica-odontologica.jar

# Comando para ejecutar la aplicación al iniciar el contenedor
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "clinica-odontologica.jar"]
```